# Proof (or reference) about $\lambda_i(A+\epsilon e_je_j^*) = \lambda_i(A) + \epsilon |v_{i,j}|^2 + O(\epsilon^2).$

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues, perturbation-theory

I'm looking for a proof (or a reference in a textbook) about the fact that
$$
\lambda_i(A+\epsilon e_je_j^*) =_{\epsilon \to 0} \lambda_i(A) + \epsilon |v_{i,j}|^2 + O(\epsilon^2),
$$
where $A$ is a hermitian matrix (having distinct eigenvalues), $\lambda_i(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $e_j \in \bf{R}^n$ is defined by $(e_j)_i = \delta_{i,j}$, $v_{i,j}$ is the $j-$th component of a unit eigenvector of $\lambda_i(A)$.

This theorem is from perturbation theory, a field I'm not very familiar with.

This is used in : Peter B. Denton, Stephen J. Parke, Terence Tao and Xining Zhang. $\textit{Eigenvectors from eigenvalues: A survey of a basic identity in linear algebra}, 2021;$
[arXiv:1908.03795](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) (page $13$).

Answer (score 3):

This is  [first order perturbation theory:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#First_order_corrections) a perturbation $\delta A$ to a Hermitian matrix $A$ gives to first order a correction $\delta \lambda$ to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ (with corresponding eigenvector $v$) equal to
$$\delta\lambda=\sum_{n,m}\delta A_{nm}\bar{v}_nv_m.$$

In this case $\delta A_{nm}=\epsilon\delta_{nj}\delta_{mj}$, hence
$$\delta\lambda=\epsilon|v_j|^2+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2).$$

The link I gave above is to the derivation in Wikipedia, if you prefer a textbook, see chapter 7 of [Introduction to Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Quantum_Mechanics_(book)) by Griffiths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read chapter 7 of the book you mentioned but I didn't see how it can help...

Comment: the chapter number depends on the edition, it's the chapter entitled "Time-independent perturbation theory", in my edition section 7.1.2 "First-order theory". But in any case, you can find the same derivation in the Wikipedia page I linked to at the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I read the Wikipedia page and section 7.1.2 of the book however I'm not familiar with quantum mechanics and I don't see how this can be considered as a rigorous proof (for example why "If the perturbation is sufficiently weak, $E_n$ can be written as a power series in λ"?).

Comment: Michelle, the perturbation theory for finite-dimensional matrices has no mathematical complexities, you are just expanding a determinant $\det(A+\epsilon\delta A-\lambda)$ in powers of $\epsilon$, which is always possible because the determinant is an analytic function of the matrix elements; the only subtlety that may appear is when an eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than 1, this is covered in the references I gave you under the heading of "degenerate perturbation theory". There is really not much more to say.

Comment: In the references that you indicate, it is admitted (not proved) that the eigenvalues can be written as power series of $\epsilon$, this isn't obvious at all (to me). If my research is right, Rellich proved this theorem (in _Perturbation theory of eigenvalue problems_) as it's explained in the introduction of _Analytic perturbation theory for matrices and operators_ by Baumgärtel. I learned that thanks to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06327.pdf) article (Theorem A.1.).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for:

1. First, I found a proof using the implicit function theorem showing that if $A(\epsilon) = A + \epsilon e_j e_j^*$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$ (which is the case) and the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, then for $\epsilon$ small enough $\epsilon \mapsto \lambda_i(A(\epsilon))$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$ and we can pick an eigenvector $v_i(\epsilon)$ such that $\epsilon \mapsto v_i(\epsilon)$ is also $\mathscr{C}^1$ (see [here](https://aalexan3.math.ncsu.edu/articles/eigen.pdf)).
2. Thanks to @JeanMarie (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137324/proof-or-reference-about-lambda-ia-epsilon-e-je-j-lambda-ia-eps?noredirect=1#comment8560110_4137324)) I saw that what I was looking for is equation $(5)$ in [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/when-are-eigenvalues-stable/) article (the above justifies taking the derivative in the article), so I get $\dot{{\lambda}_i}(0) = |v_{i,j}|^2$ $-$ where $\lambda_i(\epsilon) = \lambda_i(A(\epsilon))$ $-$ ie. $\lambda_i(\epsilon)=\lambda_i(A + \epsilon e_j e_j^*)=_{\epsilon \to 0} \lambda_i(A) + \epsilon |v_{i,j}|^2 + o(\epsilon)$.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer that satisfies you, but do note that the articles you are referring to consider the case of an arbitrary matrix $A$, which need not be diagonalizable and indeed calls for a more complicated analysis; your question (at least how I understood it) was about Hermitian $A$, where such complications do not appear (and in fact the formula you quote for $\delta\lambda$ assumes Hermitian $A$, otherwise you would have to distinguish left and right eigenvectors)